# Adding list with different length as a new column to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am willing to add or insert the list values in the dataframe. The dataframe len is `49`, whereas the length of list id `47`. I am getting the following error while implementing the code.

```
print("Lenght of dataframe: ",datasetTest.open.count())
print("Lenght of array: ",len(test_pred_list))
datasetTest['predict_close'] = test_pred_list
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-68114a4e9a82> in <module>()
      5 # datasetTest = datasetTest.dropna()
      6 # print(datasetTest.count())
----> 7 datasetTest['predict_close'] = test_pred_list
      8 # test_shifted['color_predicted'] = test_shifted.apply(determinePredictedcolor, axis=1)
      9 # test_shifted['color_original'] =

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2517         else:
   2518             # set column
-> 2519             self._set_item(key, value)
   2520 
   2521     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2583 
   2584         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2585         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2586         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2587 

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2758 
   2759             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2760             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2761             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2762                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   3119 
   3120     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 3121         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   3122 
   3123     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

How I can get rid of this error. Please help me.

Comment: Well, what do you want for the last 2 values? E.g. you can try `datasetTest['predict_close'] = test_pred_list + [0, 0]`.

Comment: I want to have a concrete solution as sometimes there are 2 less sometimes 3, And I want that it should get filled with the corresponding `open` value from dataframe.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you convert the list to a Series then it will just work:

```
datasetTest.loc[:,'predict_close'] = pd.Series(test_pred_list)
```

example:

```
In[121]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(3)})
df

Out[121]: 
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2

In[122]:
df.loc[:,'b'] = pd.Series(['a','b'])
df

Out[122]: 
   a    b
0  0    a
1  1    b
2  2  NaN
```

The docs refer to this as [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) which talks about adding or expanding but it also works where the length is less than the pre-existing index.

To handle where the index doesn't start at `0` or in fact is not an int:

```
In[126]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(3)}, index=np.arange(3,6))
df

Out[126]: 
   a
3  0
4  1
5  2

In[127]:
s = pd.Series(['a','b'])
s.index = df.index[:len(s)]
s

Out[127]: 
3    a
4    b
dtype: object

In[128]:
df.loc[:,'b'] = s
df

Out[128]: 
   a    b
3  0    a
4  1    b
5  2  NaN
```

You can optionally replace the `NaN` if you wish calling `fillna`

Comment: Only concern is the original df's index may not start from 0

Comment: @Wen true but that can be overcome easily

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir.... It is another excellent answers that I have got today.... What a day....:)

Comment: Good one. very useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can add items to your list with an arbitrary `filler` scalar.

Data from @EdChum.

```
filler = 0
lst = ['a', 'b']

df.loc[:, 'b'] = lst + [filler]*(len(df.index) - len(lst))

print(df)

   a  b
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  0
```

Answer (score 5):

You still can assign it by using `loc` data from Ed

```
l = ['a','b']
df.loc[range(len(l)),'b'] = l
df
Out[546]: 
   a    b
0  0    a
1  1    b
2  2  NaN
```

Comment: This is a nice answer if you need `NaN` filler.

Comment: Nice compact answer, don't know if explicitly passing a `pd.RangeIndex` would be more performant or not: `df.loc[pd.RangeIndex(df.index[0], len(l)),'b'] = l` +1

Comment: @EdChum yes you are right , this is more neat than the current one :-) thank you man !