# How to fix Python list comprehension ValueError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I'm learning python and need to use list comprehensions to answer a question on an assignment, but can't figure out an error I'm getting. I have a dataframe with participants, their ages, and their scores across different tests. I tried to use list comprehension to get a list of scores from participants under a certain age,

```
df['scoreunder18'] = [row for row in df['score'] if df['Age'] < 18 in row]
```

but got the following error:

```
*** ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried

```
df['scoreunder18'] = [row for row in df['score'] if (df['Age'] < 18).item in row]
```

but that just returns the values from the score column without honoring the condition.

Any help would be appreciated please and thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ValueError occurs because the entire column `df['age']` is being compared to the integer 18. However, you may encounter a different error by directing the list comprehension output right back into the DataFrame as `df['scoreunder18']`. This is because the length of the list may not match the length of the DataFrame's index.

In the example below the data will recreate the index-output length mismatch. I used `zip()` which combines each value pair in the two columns as a tuple.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'participant': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'age': [17, 21, 22], 'score': [75, 85, 95]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list_under_18 = [sc for ag, sc in zip(df['age'], df['score']) if ag < 18]
```

list_under_18 = `[75]` which has a length of one while the DataFrame index is three. To attach this as a column to the original DataFrame convert the list to a Series, which will fill in the empty values with NaN values.

```
df['under_18_scores'] = pd.Series([sc for ag, sc in zip(df['age'], df['score']) if ag < 18])
```

Here are some similar answers for reference:

[list comprehension in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646458/list-comprehension-in-pandas)

[Adding list with different length as a new column to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424453/adding-list-with-different-length-as-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe)